# Don't make me chase the upvote button in the triage queue

Tags: feature-request, review, design, user-interface, triage

When I vote <kbd>Looks OK</kbd> in the triage queue, there's a chance I may be one of the last users to do so. When this is the case, I am prompted to upvote the question I just reviewed:

> Thanks! The consensus is: this post Looks OK.
> Please remember to
>   upvote clear, useful, well-researched questions to encourage their
>   authors and help answerers identify them!

This is good! However, the vote count and buttons is bouncing all over the place and I have to chase it or wait about three seconds to click it.

I propose that either

1. A <kbd>Vote Up</kbd> button be added. This is equivalent to clicking "Vote Up" and <kbd>Next</kbd>. **Preferred Option**
2. Don't make the vote count bounce up and down for more than 500ms. (if even that long)

Comment: Tangentially related: [Why is there no facility to vote in Triage?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283673#284627). Also, this question would be better placed at meta.SO where most of Triage-related discussion happens.

Comment: In fact, Triage is only on StackOverflow... so ALL Triage-related discussion is currently happening there.

Comment: @JonArndt This question was auto-migrated from MSO to MSE when MSE rolled out.